# How to Create Jquery Two Div Resize Horizontally

Tags: jquery

I want to create two divs re-sizable horizontally but when first one hight increases according to that second height must decrease and also both have a common parent whose height & width is 100%; So when we increase or decrease the height of both divs they must keep in parent div's height;
here is my code please provide jquery codes and css codes for it; i am using jquery-1.11.2.js and jquery-ui.min.js.

`<div id="parent" style="height:100%;width:100%>
   <div id="div1"> My Data </div>
   <div id="div2"> My Data </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you create that using jquery UI resizable() and listen to that resize event

**Go to :**  [**Working Demo jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kokilajs/2o7neb6v/3/)

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="div1"> My Data1 </div> 
    <div id="div2"> My Data2</div> 
</div>
```

**jquery 1.9.1 & jquery UI**

```
$("#div1").resizable();
    $('#div1').resize(function(){
       $('#div2').width($("#parent").width()-$("#div1").width()); 
    });
```

**updated:listen for browser window resize**

```
$(window).resize(function(){
   $('#div2').width($("#parent").width()-$("#div1").width()); 
   $('#div1').height($("#parent").height()); 
});
```

Comment: btw i think this is vertical, not horizontal, but i'm trying to do some tweaks to make it work the other way too.!

Comment: Hi, It worked fine for me. But, If I am giving

border-right: 2px solid red;

for div1. It is not working